# K-out-of-N constraint in Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py, sat

I am using the Python bindings for the [Z3 theorem prover](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki) (Z3Py).  I have N boolean variables, x1,..,xN.  I want to express the constraint that exactly K out of N of them should be true.  How can I do that, in Z3Py?  Is there any built-in support for that?  I checked the online documentation, but the [Z3Py docs](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3.html) don't have any mention of any API for that.

For one-out-of-N constraints, I know I can separately express that at least one is true (assert Or(x1,..,xN)) and that at most one is true (assert Not(And(xi,xj)) for all i,j).  I also know of [other ways](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13188/755) to manually express the 1-out-of-N and K-out-of-N constraints.  However I have the impression that when the solver has built-in support for this constraint, it can sometimes be more efficient than expressing it manually.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, Z3Py has built-in support for this.  There is an undocumented API for this, that isn't mentioned in the Z3Py docs: use `PbEq`.  In particular, the expression

```
PbEq(((x1,1),(x2,1),..,(xN,1)),K)
```

will be true if exactly K out of the N boolean variables are set to true.  There are [some reports](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/755) that this encoding will be faster than naive ways of manually expressing the constraint.

To express a 1-out-of-N constraint, just set K=1 and use `PbEq`.  To express an at-most-K-out-of-N constraint, use `PbLe`.  To express an at-least-K-out-of-N constraint, use `PbGe`.

You can express this in Python like this:

```py
import z3

s = z3.Solver()
bvars = [z3.Bool("Var {0}".format(x)) for x in range(10)]
#Exactly 3 of the variables should be true
s.add( z3.PbEq([(x,1) for x in bvars], 3) )
s.check()
m = s.model()

s = z3.Solver()
bvars = [z3.Bool("Var {0}".format(x)) for x in range(10)]
#<=3 of the variables should be true
s.add( z3.PbLe([(x,1) for x in bvars], 3) )
s.check()
m = s.model()

s = z3.Solver()
bvars = [z3.Bool("Var {0}".format(x)) for x in range(10)]
#>=3 of the variables should be true
s.add( z3.PbGe([(x,1) for x in bvars], 3) )
s.check()
m = s.model()
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to access `PbEq` via the smt-lib interface? (perhaps via a tactic, or some other z3 magic?)

Comment: @LeventErkok, I don't know.  Good question!  The internal C/C++ API is Z3_mk_pbeq().

Comment: Filed a ticket here to see if the z3 folks can figure out a way: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/960

Comment: The SMT-LIB syntax is 

              ((_ at-most k) x y z u v),
               ((_ at-least k) x y z u v),
              ((_ pbge c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 k) x y z u v),
              ((_ pble c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 k) x y z u v),
              ((_ pbeq c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 k) x y z u v),

If you only use bit-vectors and PB constraints, then set the logic to QF_FD (quantifier-free finite domains). It then uses the SAT solver.