# SMTlib non overlapping but complementary Bitvectors

Tags: bitwise-operators, z3, smt, bitvector

I am struggling with the attempt to generate a correct assertion in SMTlib. The QV_BV (Bitvectors) theory is used. I use Python to generate the `temp.smt2` file and then run it using `z3`. The goal is to assert that among an arbitrary number of vectors:

1. Pairwise conjunction must be `#b0000000...00`, i.e all zeroes
2. Total disjunction must be `#b1111111...11`, i.e all ones

Roughly speaking, each vector represents the timetable of an employee, and the requirements are that all timetable slots must be taken by only one employee at a time, but all slots must be taken.

Examples are as follows:

```
(1)   |  (2)   |  (3)
      |        |
1010  |  1000  |  1000
1001  |  0100  |  0110
0100  |  0010  |  0001
----  |  ----  |  ----   <--- "disjunction"
1111  |  1110  |  1111
      |        | 
fail  |  fail  |  sat!
```

Example 1 is UNSAT, because, despite the fact that all slots are occupied,
there is a collision between the first two bit-vectors

Example 2 is UNSAT because not all the slots are taken. The LSB of a result is 0.

Example 3 is SAT because all slots are taken and no collisions.

I attempted the following approach (N and M are arbitrary numbers):

```
(set-logic QF_BV)

(declare-const x0 (_ BitVec M))
(declare-const x1 (_ BitVec M))
...
(declare-const xN (_ BitVec M))

(assert (= #b00000...00 (bvand x0 x1 ... xN)))
(assert (= #b11111...11 (bvor x0 x1 ... xN)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Only later did I notice that this is insufficient. The disjunction (OR-ing) of overlapping ones is allowed. Then I considered other bitwise operations I got lost quickly. For example, XOR-ing more than one term can be unpredictable, since:

```
xor(1, 0, 1, 0, 1) == xor(1, xor(0, xor(1, xor(0, 1)))) == 0
xor(1, 0, 1, 1) == xor(1, xor(0, xor(1, 1))) == 1
```

I can use Python to generate each pairwise assertion in the smt2 file. But since I have arbitrary many bit-vectors, it may lead to high complexity. For example, given 100 bit-vectors, there are 4950 pairs, therefore 4950 assertions. I hope we can do better than that.

So what is a possible solution? Thank you!

Edit: Note that I am not using z3py. I am writing to .smt2 file

Comment: Do these need to be bitvectors specifically, or is that just a convenient grouping mechanism? What you're describing are "at-most-k/exactly-k" constraints, which is fairly well-studied over individual boolean variables (namely pseudo-boolean solving). For you, k=1 and you're going after exactly-1 via at-least-1 + at-most-1. Z3 [supports such constraints natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081929/k-out-of-n-constraint-in-z3py). But grouped as bitvectors, as far as I know you're just going to have to "undo" that and address individual bits again.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to keep `NxM` booleans, instead of `N` M-bit vectors. Then you want to assert exactly one of each column is set. (Note that you don't need to `or` them anymore, because the first constraint will handle that.)

To assert exactly one of them is true, you can use `PbEq`, which is supported by z3. Or you can add 1 for each set boolean, and assert the sum is 1, if you want to be generic.

Note that you can still have bit-vectors if you want, if that helps in some other part of the problem. If that's the case, also create NxM booleans and set them correspondingly. (Using calls to `extract`.) And then you can have both representations and use whichever is most suitable.

PS: You said you're not using z3py. If you did, that'd definitely simplify your coding. Note that you can always convert a z3py program to simple SMTLib using the `sexpr` method of the solver. Unless you've some other reason not to do so, I'd definitely go with that.