# Is there a way to ask for at least k satisfied soft constraints in z3-Python?

Tags: constraints, z3, z3py

I know that you can add soft-constraint in z3py and then ask z3 to find a model that satisfies the maximum number of soft-constraints possible by running:

```
s = Optimize()
s.add_soft(...)
...
s.add_soft(...)
s.check()
```

My questions is what can you do if you want z3 to return any model that satisfies at least k soft-constraints. My hope is that if z3 managed to satisfy k constraints it will stop the search and return the current model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These are called k-out-of-N constraints, also known as pseudo-boolean constraints. See [K-out-of-N constraint in Z3Py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081929/k-out-of-n-constraint-in-z3py) for details.